# Do not subscribe to actions ngxs

Tags: redux, ngxs

I have an state selector and action as below

```
@Selector()
public static employees(state: EmployeeSearchStateModel) {
    return state.employees;
}

@Action(FetchEmployees)
getEmployees({ getState, setState }: StateContext<EmployeeSearchStateModel>) {
    const state = getState();
    this.employeeService.getEmployees().pipe(tap((res: EmployeeSearch) => {
        setState({
            ...state,
            loading: false,
            employees: res.userData
        });
    }));
}
```

Now, in a component, i want to use it with async pipe, but it does not work. Component declarations are as below:

```
@Select(ManageEmployeeSearchState.employees) employees$: Observable<EmployeeI[]>;

ngOnInit(){
    this.store.dispatch(new FetchEmployees());
}
```

In HTML when i try to print `<pre>{{ employees$ | async | json }}</pre>`, it does not work.. i can not see backend API called.

However, if i replace `pipe and tap` in Action with `subscribe`, everything works very well. But i do not want to subscribe?

Any leads please?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are using `pipe` operators in the state rather than calling subscribe, you need to return that Observable to NGXS so that the framework will subscribe to it for you:

```
@Action(FetchEmployees)
getEmployees({ getState, setState }: StateContext<EmployeeSearchStateModel>) {
    const state = getState();
    return this.employeeService.getEmployees().pipe(tap((res: EmployeeSearch) => {
        setState({
            ...state,
            loading: false,
            employees: res.userData
        });
    }));
}
```

Comment: Gotcha!! Silly me :( .. Thanks ton